# How to track pixel events without initializing pixel id on Shopify store?

Tags: pixel, facebook-pixel

I have two pixel ID's, one for tracking all standard events like pageView, AddToCart, Purchase etc and second one for tracking custom events like myCustomEvent.

```
    fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID_1');
    fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID_2');
```

but when I initialize both the pixel IDs in HTML Header, Shopify starts tracking all the events for both the pixels

[image]

How can i stop tracking all standard event for pixel ID 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

We can stop tracking all standard event for pixel_ID_2 by setting `trackSingleOnly` true

`fbq('set', 'trackSingleOnly', true, 'PIXEL_ID_2')`